# EditText not focusing in CoordinatorLayout with NestedScrollView

Tags: android

I have an EditText that is not allowing to Focus and type. The screen has CoordinatorLayout as a root/parent and NestedScrollView with ViewPager.

On the TOP there WILL be google map and at the bottom there are two tabs.

First tab has text content with EDIT TEXT (which is having the issue) and on the second tab there is a recyclerview.

With this layout unable to Focus and Type on the EditText on the First Tab.

### Parent Screen XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="Fragments.JobOpen">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/job_open_map_height"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <!--
            TODO:: You may use fragment to load map just below the ImageView.
            The ImageView is a placeholder I used during the design as a reference.
             -->
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/gmap_screenshot"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <!--
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />
                -->

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/job_open_nested_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/job_open_tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="@dimen/archive_card_elevation"
                android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/job_open_viewpager"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/colorFieldHint"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop">

                <!--
                TODO:: Remove the tab items ...
                I have kept it for your reference however it is useless here..
                as loading from Viewpager class..
                -->
                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/job_details" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/services_providers" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/job_open_viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/job_open_tab_layout" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### Tab 1 XML

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/app_space"
    tools:context="Fragments.JobOpenDetails">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_open_id_label"
        style="@style/TextLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_space_one_half"
        android:text="@string/job_id"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/job_open_service_label"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/job_open_elapsed_time_label"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_open_service_label"
        style="@style/TextLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_space_one_half"
        android:text="@string/problem"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/job_open_elapsed_time_label"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/job_open_elapsed_time_label"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/job_open_id_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/job_open_id_label" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_open_elapsed_time_label"
        style="@style/TextLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_space_one_half"
        android:text="@string/elapsed_time"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/job_open_time_label"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/job_open_content_barrier"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/job_open_id_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/job_open_service_label" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_open_time_label"
        style="@style/TextLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_space_one_half"
        android:text="Opened at"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/job_open_vehicle_label"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/job_open_elapsed_time_label"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/job_open_id_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/job_open_elapsed_time_label" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_open_vehicle_label"
        style="@style/TextLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_space_one_half"
        android:text="@string/vehicle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/job_open_price_label"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/job_open_elapsed_time_label"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/job_open_id_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/job_open_time_label" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_open_price_label"
        style="@style/TextLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_space_one_half"
        android:text="@string/price"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/job_open_note_label"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/job_open_elapsed_time_label"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/job_open_id_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/job_open_vehicle_label" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_open_note_label"
        style="@style/TextLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/notes"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/job_open_elapsed_time_label"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/job_open_id_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/job_open_price_label" />

    <!-- separator -->

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/job_open_content_barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:barrierDirection="right"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="job_open_note,job_open_time,job_open_id,job_open_vehicle,job_open_service,job_open_price,job_open_elapsed_time"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/job_open_id"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/job_open_elapsed_time_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- values -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_open_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="345"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/job_open_id_label"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/job_open_content_barrier" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_open_service"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Flat Tire"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/job_open_service_label"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/job_open_id" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_open_elapsed_time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="5min"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/job_open_elapsed_time_label"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/job_open_id" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_open_time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12:30pm on 12-31-2019"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/job_open_time_label"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/job_open_id" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_open_vehicle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nissan March K13 2013 Purple"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/job_open_vehicle_label"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/job_open_id" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_open_price"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$40"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/job_open_price_label"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/job_open_id" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_open_note"
        style="@style/TextContent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I am waiting in a hotel just after highway. Please contact me as you arive on spot."
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/job_open_action_barrier"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/job_open_id"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/job_open_note_label"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/job_open_action_barrier"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="job_open_note"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/job_open_edit_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/job_open_note" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/job_open_edit_button"
        style="@style/ButtonFlat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/app_space_one_half"
        android:text="@string/edit"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/job_open_id_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/job_open_action_barrier" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/job_open_cancel_button"
        style="@style/ButtonPostTheme"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/app_space_one_half"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/job_open_action_barrier" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/test_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/job_open_cancel_button" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Tab 2 XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context="Fragments.JobOpenAppliedProviders">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/job_open_provider_sort_label"
            style="@style/SortLabelText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/app_space"
            android:text="@string/sort_by"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/job_open_provider_sorty_time"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/job_open_provider_sorty_time"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/job_open_provider_sorty_time"
            style="@style/BodyMenuText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/time"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/job_open_provider_sort_distance"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/job_open_sort_divider"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/job_open_provider_sort_label" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/job_open_sort_divider"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/job_open_provider_sort_divider_thickness"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/job_open_provider_sort_divider_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/app_space_half"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/app_space_half"
            android:background="@color/colorListItemBorder"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/job_open_provider_sort_distance"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/job_open_provider_sort_distance"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/job_open_provider_sorty_time"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/job_open_provider_sort_distance" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/job_open_provider_sort_distance"
            style="@style/BodyMenuText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/app_space"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/app_space"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_space_one_half"
            android:text="@string/distance"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/job_open_provider_barrier"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/job_open_sort_divider"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.constraint.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/job_open_provider_barrier"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barrierDirection="bottom"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/job_open_provider_list"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/job_open_provider_sort_distance" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/job_open_provider_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/job_open_provider_barrier" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force the edit text to gain focus programmatically. Inside your TAB1 java class you can do the following that will force the edit text to gain focus.

```
  EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.test_text); //initialize edit text
  editText.requestFocus(); //will request focus

  //will force the keyboard to show 
  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is focusing EditText however not showing keyboard.